# Converting Indicator Columns to Counts Table?

Tags: r, contingency

In R, I am trying to convert a data frame of indicator variables into a table of counts.

My data looks like this, where A, B, C, and D are indicator variables for different conditions and ID1, ID2, ID3, and ID4 are patient ID's.

```
test <- data.frame(rbind(c(0,0,0,1),c(1,0,0,1),c(1,0,0,0),c(1,1,0,0)))
colnames(test) <- c("A","B","C","D")
rownames(test) <- c("ID1","ID2","ID3","ID4"); test

    A B C D
ID1 0 0 0 1
ID2 1 0 0 1
ID3 1 0 0 0
ID4 1 1 0 0
```

I'd like to end up with a table where it does a summary of the counts for A, B, C, and D and how they overlap:

```
  A B C D
A 3 1 0 1
B 1 1 0 0
C 0 0 0 0
D 1 0 0 2
```

Since A, B, C, and D are different variables and a given ID can have multiple entries, I'm not sure how to make this happen.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5):

Does matrix multiplication solve your problem?

```
test <- data.frame(rbind(c(0,0,0,1),c(1,0,0,1),c(1,0,0,0),c(1,1,0,0)))
colnames(test) <- c("A","B","C","D")
rownames(test) <- c("ID1","ID2","ID3","ID4"); test

test1 <- as.matrix(test)
t(test1) %*% test1
```

Comment: Oh my gosh that's perfect!  Thank you so much - I never would have come up with this!